# Cannot open database requested by the login .Login failed for user

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, database-connection, dbml

I have few aspx pages and and few tables in database. Each page connects to respective table. The purpose of each page is the same, only some condition are different. When I develop I use different database for testing data and called it "Database_DEV1" to be easy to remember. Now a problem is that only one page connects to the database (Database_DEV1) with same connection string. Other pages throws error with message:

```
Cannot open database "Database" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'xxx'
```

Why does it connect to "Database" if I provided connection string that refers to Database_DEV1?

Is it possible that this kind of error may appear at all? Do I miss something? I checked connection string I provided.

It looks like page "remembers" something different for some reason. I tried simple `SqlConnection` class and it works, but `dbml` file not.

**update**

Problem is that that Context refers to folder:
// C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0f053840_shadow\2edebf24\5576\App_Code.whnwybua.dll

At first, application connects using context that is declared in dbml. But when I do some actions it tries to connect using context which refers to dll file I described above. Why is that?

Comment: Could you show code of one of  those pages, where connection error occurs?

Comment: well, it doesn't break at any point, It just ends up with error. There are thousands of lines of some calculations so which part would be most important for you?

Comment: @RistoM I updated my post. Please look at it.